# A method to create for each user unique variables in views.py in Django

Tags: python, django, variables, django-views

I have an application that is created in Django framework that creates some statics charts like in excel based on some inputs from web where the user inserts information. I have in my views.py some functions that are processing the request from user.
The problem is, if two users for example, user_1 and user_2 that are using in same time the application, user_1 is overwriting user's_2 information.

For example in my views.py I have an variable called net_percent that it takes the value from an input from WEB interface :

```
net_percent = int(request.POST.get('net_percent', 0))
```

Is there a method or a function in this framework to create a unique variable for each user?

For example user_1 its working with **net_percent_1** and user_2 its working with **net_percent_2**

my views.py content :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import *
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

start_date = 0
stop_date = 0
sop_date = 0

qa_pr_prediction = 0
net_percent = 0

curent_week = 0
start_week = 0
stop_week = 0
sop_week = 0
```

Comment: You haven't really given enough information here. Where are you storing these variables?

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments; *edit* your question and put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to store variable names? This could be achieved by using python dictionaries.

```
d = {}
i = 0
while i < your_users_quantity:
    // generate your username (e.g.: user = "user_"+i that could result in user_1 for example)
    key = user
    // generate your value (e.g.: net_percent = whatever THIS user net_percent is)
    value = net_percent
    d[key] = value 
    i += 1
```

Then you just call d['user_1'] and you have the value of the net_percent that belongs to that user.

See this link for further reference on this useful structure: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Thanks. I will give a shot

Comment: If it solves your problem, can you please mark the answer as correct? (the green check). Feel free to add more info if the solution does not fit you.